# Python Binary Recursive Search 5.2.6 Binary.py

Tags: python, recursion, search, binary

I'm trying to solve a homework assignment where I design a function that has 2 inputs, a list of dates and a single integer (a year). The function's goal is to return True or False if the year is within the list of dates. I believe I've developed code that accomplishes this. However, the error I receive is it says I'm not completing the problem using recursion (one of the requirements). Could someone please tell me if my solution looks incorrect? As I believe my current solution does the trick right now. Thanks so much.
Peter

```
#for two versions of binary_search: one using recursion, one
#using loops. For this problem, use the recursive one.
#
#In this problem, we want to implement a new version of
#binary_search, called binary_search_year. binary_search_year
#will take in two parameters: a list of instances of Date,
#and a year as an integer. It will return True if any date
#in the list occurred within that year, False if not.
#
#For example, imagine if listOfDates had three instances of
#date: one for January 1st 2016, one for January 1st 2017,
#and one for January 1st 2018. Then:
#
#  binary_search_year(listOfDates, 2016) -> True
#  binary_search_year(listOfDates, 2015) -> False
#
#You should not assume that the list is pre-sorted, but you
#should know that the sort() method works on lists of dates.
#
#Instances of the Date class have three attributes: year,
#month, and day. You can access them directly, you don't
#have to use getters (e.g. myDate.month will access the
#month of myDate).
#
#You may copy the code from Worked Example 5.2.5 and modify
#it instead of starting from scratch. You must implement
#binary_search_year recursively.
#
#Don't move this line:
from datetime import date


#Write your code here!
def binary_search_year(searchList, searchTerm):
    searchList.sort()
    if len(searchList) == 0:
        return False
    end = len(searchList)-1
    if searchList[end].year == searchTerm:
        return True
    else:
        return binary_search_year(searchList[:end], searchTerm)

    
#Below are some lines of code that will test your function.
#You can change the value of the variable(s) to test your
#function with different inputs.
#
#If your function works correctly, this will originally
#print: True, then False
listOfDates = [date(2016, 11, 26), date(2014, 11, 29), 
               date(2008, 11, 29), date(2000, 11, 25), 
               date(1999, 11, 27), date(1998, 11, 28), 
               date(1990, 12, 1), date(1989, 12, 2), 
               date(1985, 11, 30)]

print(binary_search_year(listOfDates, 2016))
print(binary_search_year(listOfDates, 2007))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very odd assignment by itself, since recursively searching a linear data type like this list is a very bad idea and I don't know why you'd be taught to do this. Also, there'd no point in sorting it, if you don't use the fact that it's sorted in its logic - out of context, it seems like a very bad exercise.

Also, you're right in saying that your *are* searching recursively, except that it's very inefficient because of the above. So, if your answer isn't correct, it's more likely that the way you use recursion isn't considered optimal.

Since there's the suggestion there of sorting first, and the function is called `binary_search_year` perhaps the idea is that you'd sort the list, look at what's in the middle and then decide to only search the left or the right half if the middle value isn't what you're after. The assignment isn't very clear on that though.

My guess is you've previously been taught something about `binary_search` that you're not sharing in the question, which explains the above assumptions I had to make.

Something like this works:

```
def binary_search_year(search_list, search_term, list_sorted=False):
    if len(search_list) == 0:
        return False
    if not list_sorted:
        search_list.sort()
    middle = len(search_list) // 2
    if search_list[middle].year == search_term:
        return True
    elif search_list[middle].year < search_term:
        return binary_search_year(search_list[middle+1:], search_term, list_sorted=True)
    else:
        return binary_search_year(search_list[:middle], search_term, list_sorted=True)
```

Note that this solution has the added optimisation of not sorting the list again and again, but sorting it once and telling the recursive calls it's already been sorted.